# Getting a single item's details (from a list of items) display in a material ui's DialogContent from openDialog button click

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have this component where I'm getting response data from api as an array. I'm then using the map function to iterate through it and display the data in a page successfully. Beside each record, I have an action button that should display single item's details in a react material ui dialog box. The problem is that I don't know how to select an individual item and instead the dialog box is returning all details for all items in the list. I'm using a functional component.

Comment: Each Item should be a separate component, and in that have onClick which will handle interaction of single item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found a solution on this, I created a new state to hold an individual current id, used the filter method to get each element in the array and then loop through the list and return an individual item on the dialog content using the specific id.